# Redirecting application after POST to other server

Tags: java, spring, post, authentication, httpclient

I'm currently working on some piece of code in a spring application which needs to decide whether the user that is logging in should be redirected to the new site (on another server) or continue on the old one.

I've been doing this via POST with Apache HttpClient and I was able to login on the new site from the old login.

My problem is that I'm not being able to redirect the browser to the new site after logging in and "remain logged in", instead it redirects me to the login page of the new site because I'm not logged in.

```
private void redirect2NewSite(HttpServletResponse response, String docNum, String username, String passwd) {

    String url = "http://localhost:9080/website/doLogin";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("documentNumber", docNum));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwd));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    HttpResponse postResponse = client.execute(post);

    String responseUrl = postResponse.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();

    response.setHeader("Location", responseUrl);
    response.sendRedirect(responseUrl);             // This sends me to the new page login
                                        // But should send me to the home page, already logged in
}
```

The old project is using struts to redirect to controllers or jsp's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, it was a very old project which used frames in it's html. So I made the post via JSP + javascript to submit it like this:

Note the `target="_top"` attribute which allows the other webpage to be loaded outside the frame. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

```
<form action="<%=newLoginUrl%>" method="post" id="redirectForm" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="documentNumber" value="<%=docNum%>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%=userName%>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<%=userPassword%>" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A logged in session are typically based on some kind of cookie.  The cookies are attached to a domain.  In this cause if you are logging into the the first site (localhost:9080) you have a cookie there.  If you go to a different site (say google.com) you cookie is not valid there so HttpClient would not send the cookie.

If you needed to you could hand manipulate / create new cookies to make them valid for the new site.